# How to Send Multiple Email Addresses with Names in C#

Tags: c#, email

How I can send multiple email addresses with names in C#? Currently I need to load Names and Email Addresses from the database and send it.

1. So I should create array of string to store the names and email addresses first?
2. Then How I can send the email? Have to use MailMessages() or MailAddress for Multiple mail addresses?

My Code

```
while (sdrReader.Read())
{      
    ReceiverName = sdrReader["Name"].ToString();
    ReceiverEmail = sdrReader["EmailAddress"].ToString();           
}
```

// Mail to Add, in here I want to get the multiple email names and address and then send them.

```
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(ReceiverEmail, ReceiverName));



sSQL = @"SELECT * FROM EmailSystem";

            try
            {
                scConnection.Open();
                scCommand = new SqlCommand(sSQL, scConnection);
                sdrReader = scCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (sdrReader.Read())
                {

                        ReceiverName = sdrReader["Name"].ToString();
                        ReceiverEmail = sdrReader["EmailAddress"].ToString();

                }
            }



try
            {
                // Instance of Mail Server
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                // Instance of SMTP Server
                SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress);


                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(ReceiverEmail, ReceiverName));            
            }
```

Comment: Move your mail.To.Add inside the while loop and you should be ok.

Comment: Can you give me any examples? Just now I tried to load it with while but there is no data inside the while loop.

Comment: In that case its the sdrReader that is the problem. Not enough code to diagnose your problem with what you posted now

Comment: Edited, the code is at there :)

Comment: The basic code is in the answer of Sergii underneath. But if there is not data it will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sketch you might use in order to achieve your goal. I don't touch the database connection and I hope you checked that you can read data from the database. If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask.

```
// define the body of your mail
var message = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("foo@gmail.com", "John Doe"),
    Subject = "Please don't spam me",
    Body = "I will be very angry if you send me spam."
};

// if you don't use gmail, then you have to specify your own settings!!!
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("foo@gmail.com", "superPassword")
};

// I skipped the creation of connection and command.
// Don't forget to call Dispose when you finish to work with database.
while (sdrReader.Read())
{
    var to = new MailAddress(sdrReader["EmailAddress"].ToString(),
                             sdrReader["Name"].ToString());
    message.To.Add(to);
}

client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Microsoft Outlook to send email messages programmatically. See [Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/161088) for more information.

Comment: What I want is in C# :)

Comment: You can use any [code convertors](http://converter.telerik.com/) if you don't understand VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dataset or Datatable instead of data reader and iterate the values through for each.

Hope the following links will provide the better guidance to send a bulk emails.

[Send bulk email using asp.net and c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47548d/how-to-send-bulk-email-using-Asp-Net/)

[Mass Emailing Functionality with C#, .NET 2.0, and Microsoft® SQL Server 2005 Service Broker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15517/Ready-to-use-Mass-Emailing-Functionality-with-C-NE)

Comment: Can you give me some examples? I tried to use ArrayList but my code cannot run. I am still debugging about it. So what you are suggesting is

1. Use Datatable to load the data 
2. Put the data from Datatable to ArrayList
3. Then Send the data from ArrayList back to the Email sending right?

Comment: Here, I just writing pseudo code.                                    1. Bind data to datatable 2. Get the Name and Email and add it to mail message inside For..Each loop

Comment: Instead of Pseudo, can you write an example in C# for me? I am bit headache because of this.